# CloudFlare is not minifying CSS, but stripping it by deleting chunks of rules

Tags: css, caching, minify, cloudflare

And it breaks web design.

To reproduce go to your Dashboard. Go to Speed tab. And tick CSS under Auto Minify. Now Purge Everything under Caching.

CSS file before CloudFlare's minification:
http://pastebin.com/zxDfysZV

CSS file after CloudFlare's minification:
http://pastebin.com/FdF91c3y

I know it looks like a mess, it's a huge file, so just scroll to the bottom of first link and see the breadcrumbs rules. E.g. the `.breadcrumb li:before{content:' \BB ';}` In the minified version it's gone together with lots of other rules and I mean like a lot, it's not even acceptable to use such feature that deletes so much of rules.

Definition of CSS minifying on CloudFlare: `Reduce the file size of source code on your website.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when minification breaks things it means your CSS has formatting errors in it. I can't check it myself at the moment, but I suggest finding another minification service online and see what that does to your file.

Comment: Next I'd try getting the cloudflare-minified CSS and see if it validates.

Comment: It does, but it's half missing rules.

Comment: It has something to do with the `@supports (-webkit-appearance: none)` section. Remove that and see if the rest then minifies properly.  If so, you may have to load that section in a different css file that you explicitly do not minify.